# Typescript property value should be a value of another property

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a type or interface `Progress`:

```js
interface Progress {
  steps: string[],
  active: string
}

const p: Progress = { steps: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], active: 'bob' }; // Error, 'bob' not in steps
```

is there any way to state that the value of `active` should be one of the values in steps?

Another, admittedly contrived example:

```js
interface Twins {
  p1: string,
  p2: string
}

const t: Twins = { p1: 'bob', p2: 'alice' }; // Error 'alice' is not the same as p1
```

where the value of p1 and p2 should be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be using [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

What we want to say is that `Progress` has a dynamic type which is based on some type `T` and then we can use `T` to add our validation.

```
interface Progress<T> {
  steps: T[],
  active: T
}

const p: Progress<'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'> = { steps: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], active: 'bob' }; //Error


const q: Progress<'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'> = { steps: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], active: 'bar' }; //No error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYHMoQM54A8AKgHzIDeAUMsnpAA54BcyxA2gLoA0NyiYYADcIrYlQC+VKggwh6yBq3TZcBQgHIYGDBuQAfZBoBGcKHsMm4ALw3kAvJTqMWydlp0buR0+e9XbHn4EQRFWEwxjPQkAbmQAeniAUShMKGkZOQUAR2VMHHwiD10DHzMLMtsHJ3oIJlZ3bV1-Xy9KjSCBYVEy82RYhPiAOQxkaDSqIA)

The above has a repetition of the `foo, bar, baz`. You can extract it out as a constant and avoid it.

You can use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to create a read-only constant which you can use as a value and to generate a type out of it.

```
type Progress<T extends readonly string[]> = {
  steps: T,
  active: T[number]
};

const steps = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] as const;

const p: Progress<typeof steps> = { steps, active: 'bob' }; // Error
const q: Progress<typeof steps> = { steps, active: 'bar' }; // No error.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYHMoQM54A8AKgHzIDeAUMsnpAA54BcyxA2gLoA0NyiYYADcIrYlQC+VKggwh6yBq3TZcBQgHIYGDBuQAfZBoBGcKHsMm4ALw3kAvJTqMWydlp0buR0+e9XbHn4EQRFWEwxjPQkAbmQAeniAUShMKGkZOQUAR2VMHHwiD10DHzMLMtsHJ3oIJlZ3bV1-Xy9KjSCBYVEy82RYhPiAOQxkaDSqIA)

Comment: Interesting! Is there any way that typescript would be able to infer the generic parameter of Progress?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It works with methods. So you can change your approach and start with a createProgress method.But with objects this is the extent to which typescript can help you

Comment: I actually needed it for a React component, which are functions (these days). So this works perfectly.